# Help with reading javascript output in php

Tags: javascript, html-parsing, bots, php-parser

i'm trying to read automatically a javascript output with php, this is the form and the output:

```
<b>SeteZoom:</b> 
<script>document.writeln(resp)</script> 

<form name=form1 method=GET onSubmit="this.rnd.value=rand()"> 
<input type=hidden name=rnd value=""> 
<b>Você:</b> <input type=text name=msg size=30> 
</form>
```

this is the form and the output is ondocument.writeln(resp), can I read that output with PHP ?

Comment: no u cant. where does resp come from?

Comment: what does this mean "the output is ondocument.writeln(resp)"??

Answer (score 1):

Javascript runs on the client (browser), PHP runs on the server. PHP cannot know what Javascript is doing unless Javascript somehow calls the server (HTTP POST, AJAX request, etc).

Comment: So, there's nothing I can do ? I run this script on console

Comment: Maybe you can describe what you want to accomplish (your end goal, not I want PHP to read Javascript) and if I can help I will.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to use some javascript AJAX to send the data in resp to the server. Since PHP is only on the server, and anything javascript does is only on the client, the server has no knowledge of client-side changes.